# Select or Filter JSON field dynamically by value in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

having JSON column in table I can selected nested properties like...

```
SELECT '{"monday": 123}'::json->>'monday'; --> returns 123
```

...but if I want to select properties dynamically, it doesn't work

```
SELECT '{"monday": 123}'::json->>to_char(now() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific/Yap', 'day'); --> returns null
```

Is is even possible to achieve?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `FM` prefix to the day keyword. `to_char(..., 'day')` has a fixed size, meaning after `monday` there are trailing spaces. The `FM` prefix removes them:

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b1c46c4e9cb19cf0ad0d7497a8dd4594)

```
SELECT '{"monday": 123}'::json ->> to_char(now() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific/Yap', 'FMday')
```

Comment: You probably also need a `lower()` around the whole expression